# read in nested columns from json file into pandas df python

Tags: python, json, pandas, nested

I need to read in a JSON file into pandas df. JSON data looks like this:

```
{"f0_":{"id":"138307057680","ActionName":"Complete","Time":"2020-04-23-12:40:04"}}
{"f0_":{"id":"138313115245","ActionName":"Midpoint","Time":"2020-06-16-20:41:16"}}
```

I need to get rid of the first key that holds all columns in it.
I tried:

```
import json 
import pandas as pd 
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

data_pd = pd.read_json('db/my_file.json', lines=True) 
new_data = json_normalize(data_pd)
```

The error message is: `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'values'`
The desired output is:

```
id                ActionName       Time 
138307057680       Complete       2020-04-23-12:40:04
138313115245       Midpoint       2020-06-16-20:41:16
```

Currently if I print out `data_pd`, the output is:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with:

```
new_data = pd.DataFrame(data_pd['f0_'].values.tolist())
```

Output:

```
             id ActionName                 Time
0  138307057680   Complete  2020-04-23-12:40:04
1  138313115245   Midpoint  2020-06-16-20:41:16
```

Answer (score 1):

You can clean the data passed to `Pandas` before generating your dataframe like this example:

```
import json
import pandas as pd


def gen_data(file_path):
    with open(file_path) as f:
        for line in f.readlines():
            if line:
                line = json.loads(line)
                for value in line.values():
                    yield value


df = pd.DataFrame(gen_data('db/my_file.json'))
print(df)
```

Output:

```
             id ActionName                 Time
0  138307057680   Complete  2020-04-23-12:40:04
1  138313115245   Midpoint  2020-06-16-20:41:16
```

**Bonus:**

A bit of speed comparaison (I'm using an i7):

If you Clean your data first then generate your DF:

```
>> %timeit pd.DataFrame(gen_data('db/my_file.json'))
519 µs ± 1.22 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

And if you generate your DF then clean it:

```
import pandas as pd


def gen_df_method2(file_path):
    data_pd = pd.read_json(file_path, lines=True)
    return pd.DataFrame(data_pd['f0_'].values.tolist())


>> %timeit gen_df_method2('db/my_file.json')
2.66 ms ± 11.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```